# приходят ошибки java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method именно с версии андройда начиная от 5

Tags: java, android

Приходят ошибки:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Именно с версии андройда начиная от 5 версии.

Вот лог:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at smartbalkhash.smart_balkhash.firm.RUBRIC_ACTIVITY$MyAdapter.bindChildView(RUBRIC_ACTIVITY.java:213)
at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getChildView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:251)
at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:455)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2738)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1360)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1619)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2563)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2356)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Вот строка ошибки:

```
if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_VIP)).compareTo("vip") == 0) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);    
}
```

И сам биндер:

```
@Override
protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {
     view.setBackgroundColor(0XFFECE9E3);
     imgMyViewHead = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rubric_expandable_child_image);
     firm_lavri_ad_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rubric_expandable_child_ad_text);
     firm_id =   cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_ID_FIRM));
     //SET IMAGE
     path_img =   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_LINKIMAGE));
     Log.d(TAG, "bindChildView() returned: path_img" + path_img);
     if(path_img!=null) {
         bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_img);
         if (bmp != null) {
             bmp.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
             imgMyViewHead.setImageBitmap(bmp);
             firm_lavri_ad_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             firm_lavri_ad_text.setText("\"" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_AD_TEXT)) + "\"");
         }
     } else {
         imgMyViewHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_firm_placeh1);
         firm_lavri_ad_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }


     Log.d(TAG, "bindChildView() returned: " + "Welcome Back, " + String.valueOf(mPlayer.getName(RUBRIC_ACTIVITY.this)) + " !" );
     String str;

     if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_VIP)).compareTo("vip") == 0){
         view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
     }
     //SET TEXT
     txtadress =  (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.rubric_expandable_child_adress);
     txtadressreal =  (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.rubric_expandable_child_adressreal);
     txtadress.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_SHORTDESCRIPTION)));
     txtadressreal.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.FIRM_COLUMN_ADRESS)));
     view.setTag(firm_id);
     super.bindChildView(view, context, cursor, isLastChild);
 }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема пройти дебаггером и определить где именно `null` вылазит?

Comment: вот именно на своем телефоне все нормально, приложение пустил в маркет, оттуда данная ошибка приходит  именно от версии андройда 5,0 - 6,0 , хотя проверял на данных телефонах. все нормально

Comment: А эмулятор с 5 или 6?

Comment: да проверял на нескольких, и на физических

Comment: может  ли cursor быть  null?

Comment: такая же ошибка и на фрагменте иногда тоже с 5,00-6,00 : getActivity() выдает null ,

Comment: @Sun148416Sun `getActivity()` выдает `null`, когда фрагмент был убран с активити (или ещё не был добавлен), а приложение пытается отобразить данные на `view`, которого уже (или ещё) нет на экране. Обычно такое воспроизводится, если открыть новую активити и тут же выйти назад, не дожидаясь загрузки данных. Тут, пожалуй, нет единого метода решения проблемы, всё зависит от того, как и когда загружаются данные

Comment: Это все гадания на кофейной гуще, попытайтесь воспроизвести ошибку, тогда все ясно станет сразу.

Comment: Благодарствую, проблема решена, сам пропустил ошибку при обновлении раньше базы данных, тем самым вызвав ошибки при новом обновлении, извиняюсь за беспокойство))))